# Ubercart payment option without gateway?

Tags: ubercart

I'm new to this forum, and I'm maintaining a Drupal 6.x webshop using Ubercart 2.4 for a client. The client wants to add a new payment option for business to business customers. These customers wouldn't need to pay at all, but would be invoiced manually from the client.

The client would have to check weather the customer is actually a valid customer for this "payment method", and decide if they can take the order or not, but this would be a separate issue.

**How can I add a new payment method that just stores the order with shipping and billing address to my database, no more?**

**Could I refactor the "Other" option from Payment Pack?**

Comment: there is an option for bank payment or you can search any other module for payement

Comment: @monymirza, thanks for connecting. What would a bank payment consist of? I don't want any text about "pay the money here" or anything, just that the order is saved as an order and then the client will send an invoice using the order information at a later date..

Comment: yes.. check from payment settings. there will an option for cheque payment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up copying the "Other" option from payment pack. Then I changed all references to "busniess_invoice". Works like a charm!